# .NET COM Issues with VB6 in Windows 7: Event doesn't work

Tags: .net, windows-7, com, vb6-migration

I have a .NET COM DLL that is used by Visual Basic 6.  However, the CloseEvent is not working in Windows 7 and the following exception is throw.  The VB6 process has no problem to invoke the Init method.  Only CloseEvent is not working.  Both Init and CloseEvent are working fine in my XP.

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Object does not match target type. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at FMStation.VbComGateway.IVbComEventGateway.CloseEvent()
   at FMStation.VbComGateway.VbComGateway.TriggerCloseEvent()
   at FMStation.VbComGateway.VbComGateway.<.ctor>b__0(Object o, EventArgs e)
   at FMStation.VbComGateway.VbService.CloseApplication()
   at SyncInvokeCloseApplication(Object , Object[] , Object[] )...).
```

Here is the code as follow. This COM object has a Init method and a CloseEvent event.

**.NET**

```
public interface IVbComGateway
{
    void Init(string namedPipieId);
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("EA9C2EFC-7A13-4944-9901-29263F4F4B32")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IVbComEventGateway
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void CloseEvent();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IVbComEventGateway))]  //Our event source is IMathEvents interface
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IVbComGateway))]
public class VbComGateway : IVbComGateway
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void MyEventHandler();

    private readonly VbService vbService;
    private ServiceHost host;

    public event MyEventHandler CloseEvent;

    public VbComGateway()
    {
        vbService = new VbService();
        vbService.ClosingApplicationSignalReceived += (o, e) => TriggerCloseEvent();
    }

    public void Init(string namedPipieId)
    {
        host = new ServiceHost(vbService, new[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/" + namedPipieId) });

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IVbService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "PipeReverse");

        host.Open();
    }

    private void TriggerCloseEvent()
    {
        if (CloseEvent != null)
            CloseEvent();
    }
}
```

In **VB6**, I am using WithEvents to hook up this event:

```
Dim WithEvents gateway As FmsVbComGateway.VbComGateway

Private Sub gateway_CloseEvent()

    CloseApplication

    Dim number As Integer
    For number = 0 To VB.Forms.Count - 1
        Unload VB.Forms(number)
    Next number
End Sub
```

Hope someone can help.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a DLL Hell problem to me, always around in COM.  Giving that interface a [Guid] and not changing it when you update the DLL is indeed a good way to invoke DLL Hell.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon to check that the expected DLLs are getting loaded by that VB6 app.

Comment: I am pretty sure the DLL is loaded by the VB6 becuause Init was called.  Also, the above exception was throw from the COM object VbComGateway, which was created by the VB6 app.

Comment: 1) is the DLL registered?  If registering for 64x, there are some nuances.  You have to use regsvr32 from within the c:\Windows\syswow64 folder if this is a 32x DLL.  2) I assume XP was 32x and Windows 7 is 64x?      Make sure the calling app runs in 32x mode (compile for x86).

Answer (score 3):

Finally the problem is resolved.  I was just registering the dll, but not the tlb on the Windows 7 machine.

I am using WIX to create the package.  I have now added both dll and tlb fragments to the wxs script (generated by heat) to resolve this.

Comment: In my application folder I had to either remove all tlb files or generate the tlb files for the current version of the dll's. So the problem existed when there were tlb files in the folder which did not correspond with the version of the dll's in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a result of the fact that in general COM registration only the `CoClass` is registered and the `ComSourceInterfaces` interface.

This will only happen on some machines while perfectly working on other machines.

The solution that works so far is to register the TLB (either by using `regasm` with the `/tlb` argument or in code by using the Win32 functions `LoadTypeLibEx` and then `RegisterTypeLib` or `RegisterTypeLibForUser`)